# Why does an integer need an ampersand when formatting a pointer in printf while a character array doesn't in C?

Tags: c

Specifically, when I want to format the pointer of said integer. I'm working through The Art of Exploitation, and it stuck out to me in the following code snippet.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int value = 5;
    char buffer_one[8], buffer_two[8];

    strcpy(buffer_one, "one"); /* Put "one" into buffer_one. */
    strcpy(buffer_two, "two"); /* Put "two" into buffer_two. */

    printf("[BEFORE] buffer_two is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_two, buffer_two);
    printf("[BEFORE] buffer_one is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_one, buffer_one);
    printf("[BEFORE] value is at %p and is %d (0x%08x)\n", &value, value, value);

    printf("\n[STRCPY] copying %d bytes into buffer_two\n\n", strlen(argv[1]));
    strcpy(buffer_two, argv[1]); /* Copy first argument into buffer_two. */

    printf("[AFTER] buffer_two is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_two, buffer_two);
    printf("[AFTER] buffer_one is at %p and contains \'%s\'\n", buffer_one, buffer_one);
    printf("[AFTER] value is at %p and is %d (0x%08x)\n", &value, value, value);
}
```

Comment: Because the name of an array is already a pointer to the first element.

Comment: @daShier: No it isn't. It's still an array. The mechanism by which it can be "regarded" as pointer is by *decay*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although `buffer_one` is a `char[8]` type, under certain instances, such as when passed as a function parameter, it *decays* to a pointer set to the first element of the array. That pointer will be a `char*` type.

Since the first parameter of `strcpy` is expected to be a `char*` type, compilation is successful.

Answer (score 3):

`&` will yield the pointer to the value (reference it). Character arrays are already treated as pointers in that context.

I dare you to try comparing values of `buffer_one` and `&buffer_one`. They are of different types, and compiler should warn you, but the actual value should be the same, nevertheless.

```
char buffer_one[8];
assert(buffer_one == &buffer_one); // should pass
```

Note that this is different from character pointers that can be used as string variables as well (from practical point of view). Referencing a pointer yields an address to that pointer:

```
char *test = "lorem";
assert(test != &test); // should pass
```

Comment: Actually, character arrays *are not* pointers - they just decay to such in certain circumstances (like when used as function parameters).

Comment: I'm not sure that helps here to understand the difference. But I'll try to formulate (edits are welcome too) a more correct and thorough answer later, unless a more helpful emerges and the question is not actually a duplicate.

Comment: Please do so! Remember, your answer may well be looked upon by many, many people, over the coming decades. Accuracy is all! (BTW, I meant no insult to your answer - just suggesting an improvement, as many have done to posts that I've made.)

Comment: Yes, I completely agree.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does an integer need an ampersand when formatting a pointer in printf while a character array doesn't?

To print the pointer of an object like `int` or `char []`, code uses `&` to get the address of the object.

```
int value = 5;
char buffer_one[8];

printf("Address of an int: %p\n", (void *) &value);
printf("Address of an array: %p\n", (void *) &buffer_one);
```

If code does not use `&`, then the object must be or convert to a pointer.  In the following, the array `buffer_one` is converted to the address of it first element.

```
printf("Address of initial array element: %p\n", (void *) buffer_one);
```

**Conclusion** The `&value` is needed as the `int` does not automatically convert to a pointer.  `buffer_one` does not need a `&` as it converts to a pointer in this usage.  `buffer_one` can also use a `&`, like any object.

---

The address of the array `buffer_one` is the same memory location as the address of its first element. Although its is *very common*, that the last 2 prints above will print the same pointer, C does not require this.  The address of the array and the address of the `char` are *equivalent*, though not necessarily encoded the same.